# Flash package outdated

Tags: package-management, flash

when chacking (through synaptic), I am told that  the lastest version of flashplugin-installer is 11.2.202.466ubuntu0.14.04.1 , but if I search http://packages.ubuntu.com I see that the lastest is 11.2.202.468ubuntu0.14.04.1 .
Reloading the packages does not change anything.
What must I do to get the lastest version?
The results of

```
apt-cache policy flashplugin-installer


flashplugin-installer:
  Installed: 11.2.202.466ubuntu0.14.04.1
  Candidate: 11.2.202.466ubuntu0.14.04.1
  Version table:
 *** 11.2.202.466ubuntu0.14.04.1 0
        500 http://ubuntu-archive.locaweb.com.br/ubuntu/ trusty-updates/multiverse i386 Packages
        500 http://ubuntu-archive.locaweb.com.br/ubuntu/ trusty-security/multiverse i386 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     11.2.202.350ubuntu1 0
        500 http://ubuntu-archive.locaweb.com.br/ubuntu/ trusty/multiverse i386 Packages
```

I'm running Ubuntu 14.04.2 LTS

Comment: What release are you on and what does `apt-cache policy flashplugin-installer` say? Plese [edit] your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You using this [repository](http://ubuntu-archive.locaweb.com.br/ubuntu/pool/multiverse/f/flashplugin-nonfree/) and there is no version `11.2.202.468ubuntu0.14.04.1`

You should use the main server in this case or wait some days until the repository has been updated.

---

If you do not want to wait, then use the command below

```
sudo -i sed 's/ubuntu-archive\.locaweb\.com\.br/archive\.ubuntu\.com/g' /etc/apt/sources.list
```